# Can I call functions or change variables throught eventlet.backdoor in Python?

Tags: python, eventlet

I wrote this minimal code to explain my case:

```
import threading
import time
import eventlet
from eventlet import backdoor

eventlet.monkey_patch()

global should_printing
should_printing = True

def turn_off_printing():
    global should_printing
    should_printing = not should_printing

def printing_function():
    global should_printing
    while should_printing == True:
        print "printing"
        time.sleep(1)

def console():
    while True:
        print "inside console"
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.spawn(backdoor.backdoor_server, eventlet.listen(('localhost', 3000)))

    thread = threading.Thread(target=printing_function)
    thread.start()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=console)
    thread.start()
```

After executing it, I connect through telnet, import my module and call turn_off_printing().
But it not works. Do i made mistake, or it is not possible?

Comment: Printing is not stopped.

Comment: It doesn't look like the backdoor server is using the same namespace. Typing the function names said they were undefined and your variable 'should_printing' is undefined as well. I tested this while telnetted into the interpreter set up by the backdoor server.

Comment: So if it not possible, write answer and i will mark it. :)

Comment: Fyi, `global` in the global scope is useless. You only need it inside a function if you want to *write* to the global scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As fthinker said in comment above:

> It doesn't look like the backdoor server is using the same namespace.
>   Typing the function names said they were undefined and your variable
>   'should_printing' is undefined as well. I tested this while telnetted
>   into the interpreter set up by the backdoor server.

(*if fthinker reply as answer post i will delete this post*)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you pass all the variables/functions you like to access while invoking backdoor

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s=eventlet.spawn(backdoor.backdoor_server, eventlet.listen(('localhost', 3000)), globals())

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printing_function)
    thread1.start()

    s.wait()
```

Now should_printing should be visible on the python interpreter running on port 3000 and setting it to false would stop printing

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `should_printing` because the `__main__` module is different from the module imported, even if they are the same module. Check the detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

```
the executing script runs in a module named __main__, importing the
script under its own name will create a new module unrelated to
__main__.
```